# Qual è il significato di "c'è posto che" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *La malora*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> E Tobia: – Sentitela che si preoccupa per quelli della Serra. Preoccupati per la tua famiglia, o bagascia, perché tu non sai quanto n’abbiamo bisogno, col padrone che per niente viene su a mangiarci quattro robiole in una volta! – e si rimise giú a bestemmiare, per farla ancora star male. 
>         Dopo cena sentii la padrona fare a sua figlia: – Ce l’hai il velo, Ginotta? Pigliamo la strada e andiamo a pregare noi due a Cappelletto. Se non chiediamo perdono noi per lui, **c’è posto che** stanotte nostro Signore ci mandi del male a noi o alla campagna.

La mia domanda è: qual è  il significato della frase "c’è posto che stanotte nostro Signore ci mandi del male a noi o alla campagna" che appare in questo passaggio? Dal contesto è chiaro che "posto" è qui usato in senso figurato. Ho cercato alla voce "posto" in alcuni dizionari, tuttavia non sono riuscita a trovare nessun riferimento a "c'è posto che" in senso figurato.

Comment: Mi pare che qui il significato sia _può darsi che_, _può succedere che_, un'espressione dubitativa. [Qui](https://rickyproverbioblogger.wordpress.com/2016/03/19/la-malora/) puoi trovare un commento al passaggio da te citato.

Comment: @abarisone:  Ho trovato questa [questa spiegazione in un libro](https://books.google.es/books?id=0HNWAAAAYAAJ&q=%22c%27%C3%A8+posto+che%22&dq=%22c%27%C3%A8+posto+che&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJn6PNyYLcAhVDEJoKHaN0CusQ6AEIEjAC) che sembra confermare la tua ipotesi. Magari si tratta di un modo di dire piemontese.

Comment: Probabilmente sì.

Comment: Peccato che non si possa vedere quasi nessuna informazione su questo libro.

Comment: Mi sono dimenticata di dire, per si a qualcuno non funziona il link del mio commento precedente, che la spiegazione che appare nel libro è: "«c'è posto che» c'è possibilità che".

Comment: Sembra simile all'espressione usata da qualcuno “ci sta che”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mi pare che qui il significato sia *può darsi che*, *può succedere che*, un'espressione dubitativa.

Grazie a @Charo nel libro [Otto/novecento, Volume 1; Volume 4](https://books.google.es/books?id=0HNWAAAAYAAJ&q=%22c%27%C3%A8%20posto%20che%22&dq=%22c%27%C3%A8%20posto%20che&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJn6PNyYLcAhVDEJoKHaN0CusQ6AEIEjAC)  la spiegazione del significato dell'espressione che appare nelle note è:

> «c'è posto che» c'è possibilità che